# Python Query (Lottery coding practice)

Tags: python-2.7

I have a query relating to return only the last results, so here is my code:

```
    import random

    def Step_1():
        Start_Game = raw_input("Enter \'Start' to continue \n") 
        if Start_Game == 'start':                              
            print "Let the Lottery begin"
        else:
            return Step_1()
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------
    def Step_2():
            random_list = []
            for i in range(10):
                while len(random_list) < 6:
                    random_number = random.randint(1,59)
                    while random_number not in random_list:
                         random_list.append(random_number) 
                         print random_list
Step_1()
Step_2()
```

When i run this it gives me the below result,

```
Enter 'Start' to continue 
start
Let the Lottery begin
[56]
[56, 20]
[56, 20, 32]
[56, 20, 32, 2]
[56, 20, 32, 2, 23]
[56, 20, 32, 2, 23, 30]
```

However how can i just display the last result generated and discard the previous 5. I know i need to change the last bit "print" within my Step_2 function, but what do I need to add?

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
random.sample(range(1, 59), 6) # genrates 6 unique random no's in the range
```

OR to modify existing code, use a list to store previously generated random no's

```
def Step_2():
    random_list=[]
    for i in range(6):
        random_number = random.randint(1,59)
        while random_number in random_list:
            random_number = random.randint(1,59)
        print random_number 
        list.append(random_number )
```

Comment: Thanks! This also work finely! I suspect it was a typo at the end with list.append(random_number)? I have changed it back to random_list.append(random_number) and it worked perfectly fine! Thanks Mithilesh!

Answer (score 0):

For your step2() function you will probably want to use a while loop, since you do not really know, how many random numbers you need to generate until you have 6 unique numbers.

```
def step2():
    # Declare an empty list to hold the random numbers
    numbers = []
    # While we do not have 6 numbers in our list
    while len(numbers) < 6:
        # Generate a random number
        rndnum = random.randint(1,59)
        # If that random number is not yet in our list
        if rndnum not in numbers:
            # Append it to the list
            numbers.append(rndnum)
    return numbers
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked like a charm apart from at the end where I changed it from "return numbers" to "print numbers". Still not 100% sure when to use return or print sometimes. Could you please explain?

Comment: The return value is returned by the function, so you can further work with the numbers e. g. You could do `lottery_numbers = step2()` and then `print(lottery_numbers)`. If you only print the numbers in the function, you can not use them afterwards, since the numbers list belongs in the scope of the function.